# xConnect contact search by preferred email

Tags: xconnect

Here is my code for searching contact by preferred mail.

```
using (XConnectClient client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
{
    try
    {
        var queryable = client.Contacts
            .Where(c => c.GetFacet<EmailAddressList>(EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey).PreferredEmail
            .SmtpAddress != string.Empty).OrderByDescending(c => c.LastModified).WithExpandOptions(new ContactExpandOptions(EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey));

        var enumerator = queryable.GetBatchEnumeratorSync(20);

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (enumerator.Current != null)
            {
                foreach (var contact in enumerator.Current)
                {
                    if (contact.Emails() != null)
                    {
                        var email=contact.Emails().PreferredEmail.SmtpAddress;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
    {
        AnalyticsHelpers.SitecoreLogException(ex);
    }
}
```

If I use here `SmtpAddress == "sss@sss.com"` I dont get any contact. Though those contacts are showing in experience profile.

If I use `SmtpAddress != string.Empty` I am getting lots of contacts and one of contact's email address is `sss@sss.com`.

How to get only those contacts which preferred email address is `sss@sss.com`?

Also after checking some code, I have found that if I find that even if I use `SmtpAddress == "sss@sss.com"` the query still take this contact.

Comment: I think you need to change this one: .WithExpandOptions(new ContactExpandOptions(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey)) with EmailAddressList.DefaultFacetKey

Comment: update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SmtpAddress` is `[PIISensitive]`

Indexing of PII sensitive data is disabled by default.

```
[Serializable]
public class EmailAddress
{
    public EmailAddress(string smtpAddress, bool validated)
    {
        this.SmtpAddress = smtpAddress;
        this.Validated = validated;
    }

    public int BounceCount { get; set; }

    [PIISensitive]
    public string SmtpAddress { get; set; }

    public bool Validated { get; set; }
}
```

In order to include it you have to set `IndexPIISensitiveData` to `true` as shown:

https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-search-indexer/enable-pii-indexing.html#

Comment: This id definitely correct answer